# How can I delete all rows in excel that meet a certain criteria, plus subsequent rows

Tags: excel, vba

[Example of what I'm trying to get rid of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iwWv.png).

I am trying to get rid of junk data in a worksheet that appears to have been formatted to be paginated.  At the beginning of every new "page" is a cell in column G saying "Page X".  The next six rows of every page are all junk data that I want to delete, and there are hundreds of "pages".

I want to be able to write a formula that will search for every cell in the worksheet that contains the text "page" (at least in column G), and then delete that row plus the next six rows.

Comment: Can you give an example screen shot with sample data? This seems ideal for a `Union` loop + delete but seeing your sheet would make sure there is no misinterpretation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Loop through all cells in `Column G`
2. Find cells `=page` and....
3. Add these cells + the next 6 rows to a `Union` *(collection of cells)*
4. Delete the `Union` at the end

---

```
Sub Maid()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update
Dim DeleteMe As Range
Dim LR As Long

LR = ws.Range("G" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LR
        If ws.Range("G" & i) = "page" Then
            If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteMe = Union(ws.Range("G" & i).Resize(7), DeleteMe)
            Else
                Set DeleteMe = ws.Range("G" & i).Resize(7)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
        DeleteMe.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This seems to work (with the slight change of EntireColumn to EntireRow for my purposes), but the problem is the page numbers increment, so I need to find "Page 1" then "Page 2" and so on.  Is there a way to find the cells that contain "Page"? Or even just convert every cell that contains "Page" to the same value, and execute on that?

Comment: Then why wasn’t that in your initial question? Just see if the cell is like page or contains page. Use a wild card match here

Comment: Ah, I was not aware that was a possiblity

Comment: Or “if left(cell, 4) = page then”